# Paypal checkout - passing item, add only one shipping cost?

Tags: php, paypal, checkout

The cart i built add one final shipping cost based on weight and volume of articles the customer is buying, called simply $shipping. I'm currently "Passing Individual Items to PayPal" (method 2 on the guide https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside).

The only 2 variables are shipping_x and shipping2_x which don't fit my purpose. I'd want to pass only ONE shipping cost (the value of $shipping variable of my cart), is there a way?

I googled and searched it with no luck, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass `shipping` you do have to go in to detail with each item if you do not want to.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087535/paypal-shipping-issue-with-multiple-items-and-a-base-price).

You need to add another variable 'handling_cart' with the shipping cost, it will be shown in Paypal as "Shipping and handling cost".